# Chose select atribute in form based on variable value

Tags: php, html, forms

I want the value of a select in a form to be selected based on the value of a variable. Below is the code that I tried, although I always get the value female in that select, for what I suppose the select parameter is always being applied. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

> ```
>           <li><label for="sex">Sex:</label>
>             <select name="sex">
>             <option value="male" selected="<?php if(strcmp($Sex, 'male') ==0)echo 'select'; ?>">Male</option>
>             <option value="female" selected="<?php if(strcmp($Sex, 'female') ==0)echo 'select'; ?>">Female</option>
>             </select></li>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <select>  <option value="male" <?php if($Sex == 'male')echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Male</option>
    <option value="female" <?php if($Sex == 'female')echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Female</option>
  </select>
```

Empty selected="" is the same as selected="selected"